# Getting a div to scroll over a header div image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a header image fixed at the top of my webpage screen, and allow content filled divs to scroll over the image when I scroll down.

The catch is that the image at the top of the screen is sized responsively, and I cannot seem to get both aspects to work together without the image distorting, or duplicating or zooming to one part of the image!

The following is the nearest I have got to a solution:

HTML

```
<body>

  <div id="header">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/960x290" width="100%">
  </div>

  <div id="main">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
 * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }

 #header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
 }

 #main {
   font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
   color: black;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 2.5vw;
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain more on the *aspects* please?

Comment: I found a solution for you, but I need to ask: why put an `img` inside your `#header` when you can set a background image for the `#header` instead? I am asking this to understand if it is a **must** or not

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative;` to `main` and then give it a `z-index` value.

Check the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/umpn66vd/

Comment: almost, except now the gap between the `header` and `main` increases relatively as you reduce screen width?

Comment: Can you please add fiddle link of latest state of your current code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Added 'margin-top:25vw;' and removed 'position: relative;' and this solved it:

```css
* { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}

#header{
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  min-width: 100%;
} 

#main {
  margin-top:25vw;
  font-family:'Hind', sans-serif;
  background-color:white;
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:2.5vw;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=73&txt=960%C3%97290&w=960&h=290" width="100%">
</div>

<div id="main">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td>info</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain **what** it is that you did

Answer (score 0):

The root of your issues is in your `img` tag and in your `#main` element.

Your `img` tag has a fixed width of 1005px. This effectively makes your layout **not** responsive. To fix this I put your image as a `background` attribute in your `#header`.

Your `main` has a simple issue. In order to make it visible above the `fixed` property of your `#header`, I added `background-color: transparent`. In order to demonstrate the scroll over, I simply added height and padding to it, for test purposes of course, you can remove such styling anytime you like.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```css
 * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 
 #header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   min-width: 320px;
   max-width: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: url("http://placehold.it/960x290") no-repeat top center;
 }
 
 #main {
   position: relative;
   font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
   color: black;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 2.5vw;
   background-color: transparent;
   padding-top: 50vh; /* for test purposes only */
   height: 100vh; /* for test purposes only */
 }
```

```html
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="main">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```